# ODBC must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, ado.net, odbc

Consider the code below:

```
string ConnectionString = "dsn=mysql;uid=sa;DATABASE=userdb;";
string qryStr = "insert into info(code) values(@code);";
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(qryStr,con );
cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int).Value = "999";
cmd.Connection.Open();
OdbcDataReader odbcdtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();//exception "must declare the scalar  variable @code"
con.Close;
```

This code is raising exception "must declare scalar vairable @code".
I'll be very grateful if anyone can point out the mistake that is in the code above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally found the solution as given in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1090296.aspx/2/10) link.

**The Odbc interface does not recognise the use of @named variables, only ? which are taken by position.  You can use ?Param1, ?Param 2 for readability, but the position is all that is used.**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string ConnectionString = "dsn=mysql;uid=sa;DATABASE=userdb;";
string qryStr = "insert into info(code) values(?code);";
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(qryStr,con );
cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int).Value = 999;
cmd.Connection.Open();
OdbcDataReader odbcdtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
con.Close;
```

Answer (score -2):

**Worked 100% please try this**

```
byte[] imageDatas = ReadFile(strFn);
try
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    con.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("insert into students(id,name,img) values(" + txtId.Text + ",'" + txtName.Text + "',?)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", imageDatas);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("inserted successfully");
    con.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

}
```