# QueryFirst fails using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using Dapper and I'm calling QueryFirst method that returns the following error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL
>   Server]Must declare the scalar variable \"@NombreDivision\

```
    public static int GetSegmentoDivision(string division)
    {
        int res = -1;

        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT [SEGMENTID]  FROM [ACCESSCONTROL].[dbo].[SEGMENT] WHERE [NAME] = (SELECT SEGMENTO FROM M4_DIVISION_SEGMENTO WHERE DIVISION = @NombreDivision)";

            res = _odbc.QueryFirst<int>(query, new { NombreDivision = division });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.Log(ex.ToString());
        }

        return res;
    }
```

I cannot find what is it that I´m doing wrong. I even have other similar queries that are working. Can anyone help me out with this one?.

Thanks.

EDIT: I´m using `OdbcConnection` not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the problem. It seems that `OdbcConnection` does not accept parametrized queries using '@' for preceding the parameters. Instead you have to use '?'. And then send the parameters in the strict same order as they are expected to be replaced on the string.

The solution I found was to send the value right into the query. This is nor reccomended tho. But in my case I just control all the flow of the application so this solution was not Sql Injection vulnerable.

More information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16481004/637840

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43651335/637840